# Crear ficheros con nombres secuenciales

Tags: php, archivo

Hola y gracias de antemano!

Estoy empezando a trabajar con ficheros y carpetas en PHP y aunque ya soy capaz de crear un fichero *.txt y añadirle contenido, me gustaría saber, que no he sido capaz, como generar cada vez que ejecuto el formulario para crear y añadir datos que el nuevo fichero tenga un nombre diferente, es decir, comienzo generando un fichero con el nombre "noticia.txt", y me gustaría saber como en sucesivas ocasiones, el siguiente ha generar sea el "noticias1.txt", "noticias2.txt"...
os paso el código de la generación del fichero, que como os digo funciona perfectamente.

```
<form name="formu" id="formu" method="post" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    
  <input type="text" id="imagen" name="imagen" placeholder="URL de la imágen">
   
  <input type="text" id="titular" name="titular" placeholder="Escribe el titular de la noticia">
    
  <textarea id="cuerpo" name="cuerpo" placeholder="Cuerpo de la noticia Aqui. Prueba a introducir etiquetas HTML y a copiar pegar texto de otros orígenes"></textarea>

  <p>
    <button type=" submit" class="btn btn-success" name="enviar">Grabar la noticia--></button>
  </p>
    
</form>
    
<?php
  //si el formulario no se ha enviado
  // presenta el formulario
    
  if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
    
    $datostxt = "<div id='noticia'><img src='" . $_POST['imagen'] . "'><h3>" . $_POST['titular'] . "</h3>" . $_POST['cuerpo'] . "</div>";
    
    file_put_contents('noticia.txt', $datostxt) or die('<span style="color:red;font-weight: bold;">ERROR: No es posible
        escribir en el archivo</span> <a href="javascript:history.back()">Volver al formulario</a>');
    
    echo '<h2>Previsualización de la noticia grabada en el fichero</h2>';
    
    $noticia = file_get_contents('noticia.txt');
    
    echo $noticia;
  }
    
?>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! Como bien indicas con la solución 1, me funciona y es más que suficiente, sólo me quedan dos dudas si no es abusar.

1-La primera sería como podría almacenar todos las noticias en una carpeta de la raíz digamos "news" (actualmente las almaceno en la raíz y queda feo)

Había pensado algo así file_put_contents('./img'.$nombre . $i . '.txt', $datostxt) pero casca...

Lo que no sé es si no debería abrir un nuevo post...

Comment: Tanto `file_exists()` como `file_put_contents()` soportan que el "nombre" del archivo sea la ruta del mismo. Así que si, podés probar con `file_put_contents('./carpeta/' . $nombre...)`. Si mi respuesta anterior sirvió para solucionar el problema, por favor marcala como aceptada para que quede como solucionado el problema.

Comment: Intento marcarla como aceptada!!!, llevo dos días buscando algún tipo de botón!!!, ¿como se hace para dar la respuesta por buena????

Comment: Abajo, donde está la respuesta vas a ver que a la izquierda tiene la cantidad de votos (actualmente "1"), debajo hay un "check" gris, click ahí para aceptar la respuesta.

Comment: Maadre mía!, vale ya está, muchas gracias y si necesitas cualquier cosa me dices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No lo probé, pero se me ocurren 2 caminos. Hay que ver cual es más rápido o cual tiene más sentido según que archivos tengas en esa carpeta.

**Opción 1**
Asignar el nombre a una variable y chequear si ya existe un archivo con ese nombre:

```
$nombre = 'noticia';
$i = 0; // Número a asignar a la noticia

// Se ejecuta el contenido del while siempre y cuando el nombre ya exista
while (file_exists($nombre . $i . '.txt')) {
    // Incrementa en 1 el nombre del archivo
    $i++;
}

// Se sale del loop cuando el número generado NO corresponde a un archivo existente,
// con lo cual acá ya podrías guardar el archivo.
file_put_contents($nombre . $i . '.txt', $datostxt);
```

La desventaja de esto es que si por algún motivo borrás un archivo intermedio (supongamos que tenés desde noticia0.txt a noticia4.txt y borrás noticia2.txt), el nuevo archivo tendría el nombre del faltante.
Pero dependiendo de lo que estés haciendo puede ser suficiente.

---

**Opción 2**
Contar cuantos archivos hay dentro de la carpeta y asignar el número que corresponda:

```
// No estoy seguro de donde se están guardando los archivos, pero esto devuelve la ruta actual
$dir = getcwd() . '/';
$archivos = new FilesystemIterator($dir, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$cantidad = iterator_count($archivos);

// Si los nombres de los archivos empiezan en "0", entonces el nuevo archivo tiene que tener un número igual a la cantidad
file_put_contents('noticia' . $cantidad . '.txt', $datostxt);
```

La desventaja de esto es que si tenés otros archivos en esa carpeta, hay que ver como contar solo los que se llaman "noticiaX.txt".